# Sonarqube maven plugin : "The 'report' parameter is missing" when analyzing Maven Project

Tags: sonarqube, maven-3

[My error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9CIn.png)

I'm using **sonarqube 6.7.1** to analyze my maven project **(maven 3.5.2**) & **sonar-maven 3.4.0.905**. I keep getting the error "The 'report' parameter is missing". I did researches for hours but looks like almost no one has had this error. Did anyone have this same issue?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project university-service: The 'report' parameter is missing

Here is my POM.xml file:

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
  `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>`

`<groupId>com.hoang.universityservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>university-service</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>`

`<name>university-service</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: **Update** If you ever get this error, all you have to do is to upgrade to Java SDK 9!

Comment: Maybe you can post an answer ?

Comment: I just did in the last comment

Comment: I was more thinking about a stackoverflow anser, in order for people seeing this thread knowing that the subject is closed.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you ever get this error, all you have to do is to upgrade to Java SDK 9

Comment: This can not be a valid solution. Java 8 must work as well.

Answer (score 8):

In our situation, the root cause was on the Sonar server:

```
sonar.log:Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

Freeing up disk space solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. I had a 100% full HDD. Please review this before trying anything else. I didn't believe this was the issue and lost an hour looking other things.

Comment: Indeed. This was the problem in my case as well. Thanks @Gerrit Brouwer