# Snoarqube- I keep getting the error "The 'report' parameter is missing"

Tags: sonarqube

I can not seem to find any answers regarding this issue

```
5:04:56.635 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:04:56.635 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
05:04:56.635 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:04:56.635 INFO: Total time: 28.403s
05:04:56.849 INFO: Final Memory: 63M/1435M
05:04:56.849 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:04:56.849 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
The 'report' parameter is missing
05:04:56.850 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
05:04:56.850 DEBUG: Execution stop
```

Comment: Would using java 9 as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/48575566/6309 help?

Answer (score 4):

For me, this was that the SonarQube server had a full HDD

Comment: Same here. the fun part is that even with -X it doesn't say anything about hdd space.

Answer (score 0):

Re-run SonarQube using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.